# PostgreSQL: Access to database denied

Tags: postgresql, connection, installation

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04 server. The database instance seems to run fine in general and when I try and connect from pgAdmin III via localhost on the server machine itself, there is no problem.

Whenever I try to use the LAN address `192.168.1.16` from the server, I get the error "`Access to database denied.`"

From what I gather, the common culprit in these sorts of situations seems to be the configuration described in the `pg_hba.conf` file, which currently contains the following:

```
host all all 192.168.0.1/32 md5
```

As far as I understand, the instance should accept all users. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I just tried adding more hosts, no luck..

local, hostssl, hostnossl

Same with 1/24 instead of 1/32 (my server is 16 anyway)

Comment: What's the full, exact text of the error message? The original (not translated back to English) is fine, it's more helpful to have the exact text.

Comment: Tatalia, do a test. Try to replace the ip address by "0.0.0.0/0" and replace "md5" for "trust". Don't forget to restart the postgresql service.

Comment: If you give access to `192.168.0.1/32` and connect from `192.168.0.16`, denied access seems like the expected result. Give access to `192.168.0.0/24` for the subnet or `192.168.0.16/32` for just this one host.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are trying to connect from `192.168.1.16`, however, your `pg_hba.conf` is allowing only `192.168.0.1` (that's what the `/32` means).

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks to learn more about CIDR notation.

If you want to allow `192.168.1.16` only you can add the following line at your `pg_hba.conf`:

`host all all 192.168.0.16/32 md5`

Then, run `pg_ctl reload` to apply the change made above.

This answer is assuming that you have verified the `listen_address` parameter  in your `postgresql.conf` file and it's binding the correct IP values.